# creating metadata of table in Sink/Target in Data Factory automatically

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is it possible on Azure Data Factory to create the table definition in the target/sink database. SSIS used to create the metadata automatically based on the Source/ Transformation in the pipeline. ADF does not seem to have that option but I am new to it so maybe non the wiser as to how to do it on the fly or any hidden options without having to script the table on the target destination

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Data Factory (ADF) [Copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#auto-create-sink-tables) does support creating the sink table at runtime but only for certain data sources:

- Azure SQL Database
- Azure SQL Database Managed Instance
- Azure Synapse Analytics
- SQL Server

See [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/copy-activity-in-azure-data-factory-supports-creating-destination-table-automatically/) for more details.

[image]